# I didnt get the user information on session callback using Nextauth methode

Tags: next.js, next-auth

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'Credentials',
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                const { email, password, csrfToken } = credentials;
                const res = await fetch('api-url', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        csrfToken,
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
                });

                const user = await res.json();
                if (res.ok && user) {
                    return user;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            },
        }),
    ],

    pages: {
        signIn: '/login',
    },
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
    },

    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user, session }) {
            console.log('jwt call back',token,user,session);
            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token, user }) {
            console.log('session call back',session,token,user);
            return session;
        },
    },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

iam using NextJsAuth methode to integrate the api when i logged in using this methode
inside the session callback i didnt get the return user informations what i do

i need to get the logged user informaions on session callback to store and display
when user logged in i only get the csrf token not get the logged user informations
using the above methode

iam using the callback functions there but the data only returned in the csrf token and other informatins
`